# Casting strings to enums

Tags: enums, casting, system-verilog

Is there a way to cast a string to enum in system verilog ?

```
typedef enum {ABC1,ABC2,ABC3} abc;

program Test ;
    abc x1;
    string teststring;   
    initial
    begin
        teststring="ABC2";
        x1=abc'(teststring); // Static cast doesn't work
        $display("[%s][%0d]",teststring,x1);
    end
endprogram
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting is by value, not name. Given that you are using the default enum data type (int) and not assigning values to any identifier, then `ABC1`, `ABC2`, and `ABC3` have the values of `0`, `1`, and `2` respectively (all of type int).

Casting a sting to this `enum` is about the same as casting it to an `int`. `int'("ABC2") == 32'h41424332` and does not match the value of any enum identifiers.

Options to get desired functionality:

1. Make a function that goes through the list and compares names:

   ```
   function abc a2e(input string s);
       a2e = a2e.first;
       repeat(a2e.num) begin
           if(a2e.name == s) return a2e;
           else a2e = a2e.next;
       end
       assert(0) else $error("Identifier '%s' not in enum abc",s);
   endfunction
   ```

   More on enum methods: [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) section 6.19.5
2. Associative array lookup: (See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) sections 7.8 & 7.9)

   ```
   abc lookup[string];
   ...
   x1 = abc.first;
   repeat(x1.num) begin
       lookup[x1.name] = x1;
       x1 = x1.next;
   end
   ...
   teststring="ABC2";
   /* Without protection: Non-match creates new entry for with the value
      of abc.first (or '{default:???} if specified) and returns the value */
   x1 = lookup[teststring];

   // With protection
   if ( lookup.exists( teststring ))
       x1= lookup[teststring];
   else
       assert(0) else $error("Identifier '%s' not in enum abc",teststring );
   ```
3. If the enum identifiers are 1 to 4 characters long value doesn't matter, make the name the value. `typedef enum {ABC1="ABC1",ABC2="ABC2",ABC3="ABC3"} abc;`

   - To long to write? Try the equivalent:

     ```
     typedef enum {ABC[1:3]="ABC1"} abc;
     ```
   - Need more the 4 characters? Assign the data type.

     ```
     typedef enum bit[5*8-1:0] {ABC[10:19]="ABC10", ABC[20:29]="ABC20"} abc;
     ```
   - More on Enumerated type ranges: [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) section 6.19.2

---

Note: The above are all functionality existing since IEEE Std 1800-2005, this version of the LRM must be purchased to read.  The 2012 version is free from IEEE, hence the references to this version.